# Html page elements getting overlapped to another page while stacking multiple page using section tag

Tags: html, css

I made few html pages and while stacking them all together to the main html page(index.html) using `<section>` tag, text alignment and their position got messed up. But Those pages run perfectly fine while I run them separately. I think CSS caused the problem, I tried to find out the problem but couldn't. I have given all the codes below. I need help. Thanks in advance.

```css
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding:0;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;

}
body{
    background: url("background0.jpg") no-repeat;
    
    background-size: auto 100%;
   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
 
}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
       
}

.logo{  
    float:left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;    
}



nav{
    padding: 15px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

ul{
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 550;
    
    
    
    
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* added this line for child absolute positioning */
    position: relative;
    
    padding: 5px 5px;
    color: black;    
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
    
}



.home{
    
    padding: 4px 15px;
    
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
 
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 18px;
}

.home:hover{
    background-color: #cce0ff;
}


.events{
    
    padding: 4px 15px;
    
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
 
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 18px;
}

.events:hover{
    background-color: #cce0ff;
}

.activities{
    
    padding: 4px 15px;
    
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
 
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 18px;
}

.activities:hover{
    background-color: #cce0ff;
}

.contact{
   
    padding: 4px 15px;
    
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
 
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 18px;
    
}


.contact:hover{
    background-color: #cce0ff;
}

.panel{
        
    padding: 4px 15px;
    
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
 
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 18px;


}
.panel:hover{
    background-color: #cce0ff;
    
}


ul li ul {
    
    position: absolute;
    background: whitesmoke;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 5rem;
    
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    
    left: 0;
     /* same as li height so that there is no space between Panel and the ul to preserve hover */
    top: 1.75rem;
  
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
 
  }
  
  ul li:hover > ul,
  ul li ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    
  }
  
  ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    /* dropdown  */
    margin: 10px 24px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }


.covid{
    
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    /* background:#7ac2ff; */
    background: #12c2e9; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,  #c471ed, #f64f59); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  #c471ed, #f64f59); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+,
   Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    margin-top: -25%;
    
    
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
    color:black;
    
    transition: 0.2s;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}


.container {
    text-align: left;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 140px 90px;

}

h1{
    font-size: 3.2em;
    font-weight: 750;
}

.container p{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 1.4em;

      
}

.container a
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    background:#7ac2ff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 650;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

.container a:hover{
    letter-spacing: 6px;

}




#section{

    background-size: auto 100%;  
    position: absolute;
    
    
    /* overflow: scroll; */
    /* display: inline; */
    /* display: inline-table; */
    /* min-height:500px; */
    /* display: block; */
    
    
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.s-history img{ 
    float:left;
    
    height: 400px ;

    width: 450px; 
     
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 50px;  
    
   
}




.s-container {
    text-align: left;
    
    width: 40%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
   

    display: inline-block;
  
    background: whitesmoke;
   
    
    /* box */
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 70px;

    text-decoration: none;
    /* text position */
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
   
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
                0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
                0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
                0 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.07),
                0 16px 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
                0 32px 64px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   

}

.s-container h1{
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 750;
}

.s-container p{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.4em;      
}


.ac-container {
    text-align: left;

    display: inline-block;

    text-decoration: none;
    /* text position */
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}

.ac-container h1{
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 750;
}

.ac-container p{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 550;

      
}

/* puts full image in a certain position */
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    display: block;
}

.ml-container{  
    float:left;
    
    height: 250px ;
    width: 450px; 
     
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 70px;   
   
    text-align: left;
    
    background: whitesmoke;
       
    /* box */
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 395px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;

    text-decoration: none;
  
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
   
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
    0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
    0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
    0 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.07),
    0 16px 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
    0 32px 64px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
   
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   

}

.ml-container h2{
    font-size: 2.3em;
    font-weight: 450;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -230px;
    margin-left: 360px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-right: 70px;

}

.ml-container p{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.4em;  
    
    
    position: absolute;
    
    margin-top: -170px;
    margin-left: 360px;  
    
    margin-right: 470px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.ml-container a{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background:#7ac2ff;
    padding: 5px 15px;
        
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 550;
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

    position: absolute;
    
    margin-top: -90px;
    margin-left: 360px;  
    
    margin-right: 470px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;


}

.cad-container{ 
    float:right;
    
    height: 200px ;
    width: 290px; 
     
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-right: 90px;   
   
    text-align: left;
      
    background: whitesmoke;
   
    
    /* box */
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 180px;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-left: 0px;

    text-decoration: none;
  
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
   
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
    0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
    0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
    0 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.07),
    0 16px 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 
    0 32px 64px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
   
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   
}

.cad-container h2{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 160px;
    margin-right: 40px;

}

.cad-container p{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.4em;  
    
    
    position: absolute;
    
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 10px;  
    
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.cad-container a{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background:#7ac2ff;
    padding: 5px 15px;
        
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 550;
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

    position: absolute;
    
    margin-top: 125px;
    margin-left: 10px;  
    
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;


}


.more-text{
    text-align: left;

    /* display: inline-block; */

    text-decoration: none;
    /* text position */
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 470px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}


.more-text p{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 550;
      
}

.more-text a
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    background:#7ac2ff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
   
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 650;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color:black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

.more-text a:hover{
    letter-spacing: 2px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo project</title>
    <link rel = "icon" type = "image/png" href = "clubicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    

    
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- <header> -->
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="logo1.png">
    
                    <img src="logo2.gif">
                </a>
            </div>
    
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="events">News & Events</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#" class="activities">Activities</a></li>
                    
                    
                  
                    <li><a href="#" class="panel">Panel</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">2021</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2020</a></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                   
                    <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="covid.html" class="covid">About COVID19 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="container">
            <h1>This is a demo text </h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure </p>
                 <a href="membership.html">Join us</a>
    
        </div>
    <!-- </header> -->

    <section id="history">
        <div class="s-history">
            <img src="Looking_history.png">
        </div>
    
    
     
        <div class="s-container">
            <h1>Have a Look on Our History </h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu.</p>
    
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse .</p>
                
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                 
    
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="activities">
        <div class="ac-container">
            <h1>Our Club Activities</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure </p>
                 
    
        </div>
    
        <div class="ml-container">
           
            <img src="ML .jpg">
            
            <h2>Machine Learning</h2>
            <p> Our club members trained a neural network of a dataset containing pictures of x-ray, 
                        classified into two categories. Pneumonia and Normal. They also developed.....</p>
            <a href="">Read More</a>            
    
            
        </div>
    
    
        <div class="cad-container">
           
            <img src="cad.jpg">
            
            <h2>CAD(Computer Aided 
                <br>Design)</h2>
            <p>Here are some designs we did for both <br>learning purposes and as projects.....</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>            
    
            
        </div>
        <div class="more-text">
            
            <p>If you want to see more activities of our club, you can
                press the link below.
            </p>
                 <a href="#">See More Activities</a>
    
        </div>
    </section>
    

  
        
       
        
        



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your design has fundamental responsiveness problems.  I played around with it and it would take me too long to set you up into the right direction.  Learn responsive design.  I will suggest bootstrap, just to understand how you can align things.  Sorry, my 2 cents.

Comment: just to add to why individual pages work, yet when combined, they do NOT is because each individual page has their own 100% space.  When you combine them, they run into each other for the reason that they are NOT given the appropriate elemental space.  Look into column properties in Bootstrap, like col-md-12 is 100% width, col-md-6 is 50%, col-md-2 is 20% and so on.  You also add col-sm-etc beside the full screen style property which you make col-sm-12 e.g., so that the width of a smaller percentage column turns 100% on mobiles.  Look into it, just to give you some direction.

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Mugé I appreciate your valuable response.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at everything but from what I could see your problem is with using the property:
`position: absolute;`
In several places in your sections try to deactivate them to see a more finished result and then adjust your sections.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ac-container {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

in the above CSS part, just remove the position: absolute, and it will work fine.